# Posicionar div em relação a uma imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo uma especie de mapa na minha aplicação, onde uma imagem que pega a tela toda tem vários botões sobre ela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento, eu posiciono os botões dessa forma:

```
.btn_padaria{
    left: 75.00%;
    top: 20.25%;
}
```

No mobile, estou fazendo da mesma forma, só que a imagem de fundo é outra, mostrando uma perspectiva de cima

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que no mobile, a altura da imagem é maior que a tela, logo para visualizar o botão "crediario" teria que rolar a tela, porém mesmo que eu coloque `top:100%` nesse botão, ele ainda NÃO fica no final da imagem e sim no final da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Lendo na diagonal... você pode criar um offset para compensar a altura e largura do ecrã. Numa solução parecida onde a precisão era crucial usei o elemento `canvas`do html5 para me auxiliar com as posições das minhas legendas.

Comment: Não preciso que seja 100% preciso , e acho que o canvas é demasiadamente trabalhoso para o que eu necessito. Mas eu ainda não tinha pensado nisso, caso não encontre uma solução mais simples tento com o canvas mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode tentar colocar `position:absolute` no `btn` e colocar `bottom:0` ai ele prega no final do elemento pai, é importante o pai ter `position:relative` para o btn ficar relativo a ele.

Veja um exemplo simples do posicionamento. Repare que a div pai tem 120vh, ou seja 20% a mais que a altura da tela visível.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120vh;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;
}
.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="btn">btn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo no mobile, estou tentando no Desktop agora!! valeu!

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha qualquer problema me fala. Eu usei a medida em PX, mas vc pode usar em % também! Só coloquei em PX pq está colado no canto então nesse caso não faz muita diferença, mas como falei pode usar tipo 1% ou 2% se preferir no bottom / left

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver de uma forma mais "precisa"

Eu basicamente utilizei o Javascript para pegar a largura da tela e da imagem e depois eu subtrai(tela - imagem). 
Depois de ter feito isso eu tenho o tamanho em pixels do espaço que está sobrando na tela. Divido por dois, pois a imagem está centralizada.

Agora basta pegar as dimensões da imagem, dividir por 100, multiplicar pela porcentagem que o botão(div) vai ficar sobre a imagem e, por fim, somar o valor sobrando.

```
  var wid = document.getElementById('img-planta').clientWidth; /*Pega a largura da imagem*/
  var hei = document.getElementById('img-planta').clientHeight; /*Pega a altura da imagem*/
  var w = window.innerWidth; /*Pega a largura da janela*/
  var h = window.innerHeight; /*Pega a altura da janela*/

  var posWid;
  var posHei;
  var auxWid;
  var auxHei;

  auxWid = (w-wid)/2; /*Acha o valor em pixels das sobrar na largura*/
  auxHei = (h-hei)/2; /*Acha o valor em pixels das sobrar na altura*/

  posWid = (wid/100) * 50 + auxWid; /*Calcula o valor em pixel que será aplicado no style left para posicionar o botão*/
  posHei = (hei/100) * 70 + auxHei ; /*Calcula o valor em pixel que será aplicado no style top para posicionar o botão*/
  document.getElementById('btn_deposito').style.left = posWid + "px"; /*Seta o style da div*/
  document.getElementById('btn_deposito').style.top = posHei + "px";/*Seta o style da div*/
```